# using redirect and if multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorcery

My question is actually fairly simple, how do I make a create action which checks if a user is logged in, and if she/he is then redirect to the dashboard instead of rendering the index page where they've got links and stuff to go to and sign up. Also why is the code below not working.

class UsersController < ApplicationController

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  if current_user.nil?
    redirect_to dplace_index_path
  if current_user
        @user = User.new(params[:user])
      if @user.save
          auto_login(@user)
          redirect_to dplace_index_path
  end
end
end
end
end
```

Comment: what's the error you are getting ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't doing what you expect because the if statements are actually nested (you want `elsif` with this same structure -- or see my suggested fix below). Here's what your code, when properly formatted, actually looks like:

```
def create
  if current_user.nil?
    redirect_to dplace_index_path
    if current_user
      @user = User.new(params[:user])
      if @user.save
        auto_login(@user)
        redirect_to dplace_index_path
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Logically, you will never get down into the second `if` statement, because `current_user` must be `nil` to enter the first. Try something like this instead:

```
def create
  if current_user
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      auto_login(@user)
      redirect_to dplace_index_path
    end
  else
    redirect_to dplace_index_path
  end
end
```

I rearranged the code, but it should logically do what you want now. I put the "happy path" first (the `current_user` exists), and moved the redirect into the else statement.

Comment: In that case "current_user" must be true, I don't want that either. So "elsif" is a preferred and good way?

Comment: `current_user` doesn't have to be `true` -- it just has to be "truthy". When `current_user` is set to a user object, it will evaluate to `true` with the `if current_user` condition. When `current_user` is `nil` (which is what you were checking for originally), `if current_user` will evaluate to `false` and fall through to the else statement. There's nothing wrong with using an `elsif` in your code, but in this instance it's not necessary. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

**General user authentication:**

```
 def create
      user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to dashboard_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
      else
        flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
        render "new"
      end
    end
```

Comment: I kinda think that the answers above very a little more easy and simplified. Thanks anyway though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def create
  if current_user.blank? # .blank? will check both blank and nil
    # logic when user is not logged in
    redirect_to index_path
  else 
    # logic when user is logged in
    redirect_to dashboard_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
  redirect_to dplace_index_path unless current_user
  # no need to check current_user again
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    auto_login(@user)
    redirect_to dplace_index_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Really?! I kinda felt that not specifying that could lead to some kind of exploit by others, like hackers and such? You sure?

Comment: Can I add this to the new action instead of the create action. Could that lead to some kind of exploit possibilities?

Comment: That code will indeed continue to execute the remainder of the action even if there is no current_user

Comment: @FrederickCheung is right. Don't do this. Rails will execute the entire method and buffer the output before executing `redirect_to`. `redirect_to` is not the same as a method `return`. At the very least, you'll need to write `redirect_to dplace_index_path and return unless current_user`.